# iOS & h264 fixed framerate

Tags: ios, h.264, fixed, frame-rate

I'm recording some video using AVAssetWriter and AVAssetWriterInput.
Later on, i'm opening the video files with some H264 analyzers and I see that the H.264 SPS does not contain any timing info (hence the frame rate is not fixed).
Is there any way to tell iOS to use fixed frame rate and add the timing info into the SPS?

I tried to disable auto exposure and set min & max frame rate values to my video AVCaptureDevice but it didn't help too much.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

SPS does not contain any timing information. You may want to store to mux the H.264 frames in the MP4/MPEG2TS containers.